# VLC Player in MacOs sierra doesn't shows the video window I just hear the audio of the video files

Tags: mac, audio, video, vlc-media-player, macos-sierra

I have MacOs Sierra, and installed the latest version of VLC Player. 
I tried playing a lot of video types mpg, avi.... 
This is what I see [image: VLC Main Window]
How can I show the video window.
I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the video is in the second "VLC media player" window?  Trying hitting Command-` (that's backtick above the tab key) and see if it switches to that window.

Comment: I tried that, nothing happened.